# I need help with proofs using mathematical induction: $2+7+12+17+...+(5n-3)=(\frac{n}{2})(5n-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction, arithmetic-progressions

I need help with this problem: $2+7+12+17+...+(5n-3)=(\frac{n}{2})(5n-1)$

Comment: Yes and I replaced the n's with (n+1), not sure if thats what I am supposed to do. Did it on other equations so thought maybe it would work here

Comment: Suppose that we know for a specific $k$ that $2+\cdots +(5k-3)=\frac{k}{2}(5k-1)$. Add $5k+2$ to both sides. show that on the right-hand side we get $\frac{k+1}{2}[5(k+1)-1]$.

Comment: ok yes thats what I have on the right, what would be on the left?

Comment: How familiar are you with the process of induction? Your explanation of what you did suggests to me that you don't understand it very well. I'll try and post an answer below which helps. Edit: Peter Tamaroff's answer is excellent and is essentially identical to what I was going to post.

Comment: Ive done this before, dont remember much. So not very familiar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving arithmetic series by induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873822/proving-arithmetic-series-by-induction)

Comment: @MiceElf I'm not quite sure about the target because it [the target question] is motivated by and largely about a typo in some book. In particular, the formula at the top there is wrong, making it less useful as a reference, yet we can't correct it without changing the meaning of the question.

Comment: @epimorphic Retracted, but there ought to be a target for "sum of arithmetic sequence by induction"...

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at $$\sum_{k=1}^n (5k-3)$$

This is  $$5\sum_{k=1}^n k-\sum_{k=1}^n 3=5\sum_{k=1}^nk -3n$$

Do you know what $$\sum_{k=1}^n k $$ is?

---

The claim is true for $n=1$, since $$2=\frac 1 2 (5-1)$$

Assume the claim is true for $n$, and look at $n+1$. This is $$\tag 1 2+7+\cdots+5n-3+5(n+1)-3$$

The induction hypothesis is that the first $n$ terms sum up to $$\frac{n(5n-1)}2$$ thus $(1)$ is $$\frac{n(5n-1)}2+5(n+1)-3$$

Can you show this is $$=\frac{(n+1)(5(n+1)-1)}2\text{ ? }$$

Comment: yes i have tried this

Comment: how did you transition to that very last step? ... to get everything in a fraction over 2?

Comment: I am asking *you* if you can show that the penultimate expression equals the last expression. You need to do some algebraic meddling.

Answer (score 0):

$2+7+12+17+...+(5n-3)=(\frac{n}{2})(5n-1)$

This equality holds true for n=1,2,3....... $\ $so we suppose it will hold true for n=k

$2+7+12+17+...+(5k-3)=(\dfrac{k}{2})(5k-1)$

then we will check it for $n=k+1 $
$$2+7+12+17+...+(5k-3)+(5k+2)=(\frac{k+1}{2})(5k+4)$$
$$(\frac{k}{2})(5k-1)+(5k+2)=(\frac{k+1}{2})(5k+4)$$
now  we try to prove LHS=RHS

$$\frac{(5k^2-k)+(10k+4)}{2}$$
$$\frac{(5k^2+9k+4)}{2}$$
$$\frac{(5k^2+5k+4k+4)}{2}$$
$$\frac{5k(k+1)+4(k+1)}{2}$$
$$\frac{(k+1)(5k+4)}{2}$$

hence proved..

Comment: any doubt,suggestion highly appreciated

Comment: where comes the `5k+2` from? And where comes the `5k+4` from?

Comment: @superkytoz When we test for n=k+1 at that point we put n=k+1 in last term that's where 5k+2 and 5k+4 came.