# Proving arithmetic series by induction

Tags: summation, induction, arithmetic-progressions

How do I prove this statement by the method of induction:

$$
\sum_{r=1}^n [d + (r - 1)d] = \frac{n}{2}[2a + (n - 1)d]
$$

I know that $d + (r - 1)d$ stands for $u_n$ in an arithmetic series, and the latter statement represents the sum of the series, but I'm not sure how to prove them by induction.

If I let $n = k$:

$$
\sum_{r=1}^k [d + (r - 1)d] = \frac{k}{2}[2a + (k - 1)d]
$$

the next step is to realize that the following term, $k + 1$, is equated to:

$$
\sum_{r=1}^{k+1} [d + (r - 1)d] = \sum_{r=1}^k [d + (r - 1)d] + [d + (k + 1 - 1)d]
$$
$$
= \frac{k}{2}[2a + (k - 1)d] + d + dk
$$
$$
= \frac{k(2a + dk - d) + 2d + 2dk}{2}
$$
$$
= \frac{2ak + dk^2 - dk + 2d + 2dk}{2}
$$
$$
= \frac{dk^2 + dk + 2ak + 2d}{2}
$$

What's the next step I take? Do I substitute back in $k = n - 1$?

Comment: For proving a statement $p$ using induction: First prove that the base case is true. Here verify the formula for $n=1$, next you have to assume that $p$ is true for some $k$ and then try to prove that $p$ is true for $k+1$(I assume you were showing this in your post). So, the only thing left in your proof is verifying for $n=1$.

Comment: Induction does not allow you to substitute $k$ for $n$ and write the result as if it is proven. Rather, to use induction means that you have to show that if the result is true for some $n$, then it is also true for $n+1$, and you also have to show that the result is true when $n=1$ (or some other base case).

Comment: I understand about the base case, but I didn't know how I could prove it is true for $k + 1$. How does the last line prove true-ness?

Comment: Small typo, I think. Shouldn't be $a + (r - 1)d$?

Comment: @IvoTerek Not sure - that's how it appeared in the book :) Does that change things?

Comment: Yes. There no $a$ in the LHS, but it magically appears on RHS?

Comment: I'll answer your question bearing that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier way. Notice that: $$\sum_{r = 1}^n a + (r-1)d = \sum_{r = 1}^n a + \sum_{r = 1}^n rd - \sum_{r = 1}^n d = na + d\left (\sum_{r = 1}^n r\right) - nd $$

Now, just prove by induction that $$\sum_{r = 1}^n r = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
which is much easier, and manipulate the previous expression to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense, and is in line with the approach taken in the book. Plus they give you the sum of $r$ and say you can assume it is true :)

Comment: You can assume that sum? Life is good haha

Answer (score 2):

The $r$th term, $u_r=a+(r-1)d$ with $u_1=a$ be the first term & $d$ be the common difference

If $\displaystyle S_n= \sum_{r=1}^nu_n=\frac n2[2a+(n-1)d]$

$\displaystyle\implies S_{n+1}=\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{n+1}u_n=S_n+u_{n+1}=\frac n2[2a+(n-1)d]+a+nd$
$\displaystyle\implies S_{n+1}=(n+1)a+d\cdot\frac n2(n-1+2)=\frac{n+1}2[2a+(n+1-1)d]$

Comment: Can you explain how you got from $\frac n2[2a+(n-1)d]+a+nd$ to 
$(n+1)a+d\cdot\frac n2(n-1+2)$?

Comment: @hohner, $$\frac n2[2a+(n-1)d]+a+nd=an+d\frac n2(n-1)+a+nd=a(n+1)+d[\frac n2(n-1)+n]=?$$

Comment: I get $a(n + 1) + \frac{n}{2}[d(n - 1) + nd]$